# Place chapter title between two lines

Tags: titles, chapters, rules

I want to place a chapter title between two lines. The lines shall be on the left and the right side of the centered title like in this screenshot:

[image: Desired result]

Note that the lines are slightly *overhanging* the text below. It would be nice if I could do the same. Obviously the length of the chapter titles is varies, so the solution needs to automatically adapt to the length.

By now I have the following:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1pt \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{60\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
          {\color{headings}
            \scshape \large \@chapapp{} \thechapter
          }
        \par\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \itshape #1\par\nobreak
    \thickhrulefill
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{chapter}{12}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Implementation}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

which gives me this:

[image: Current state]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an idea:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir

\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1pt \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{60\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
          {
            \scshape \large \@chapapp{} \thechapter
          }
        \par\bigskip\nobreak
        \interlinepenalty\@M
    \makebox[\linewidth]{%
      \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth+4em]{\Huge \itshape \thickhrulefill~\raisebox{-.5ex}{#1}~\thickhrulefill}}\par\nobreak
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{chapter}{12}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Implementation}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I've placed the header (only the chapter title) inside a box of with `\linewidth`, which ensure no overfull `\hbox`es. Then, inside that box, I place two `\thickhrulefill`s beside the actual title, inside another box of width `\linewidth+4em`. Since these boxes centre their content by default, it allows for a 2em overhang on either side.

A slight raise of -1ex (or a drop) centres the heading with respect to the rules.

Comment: Seems to do the job but be careful if your chapter title is too long, it won't break the line...

Comment: @LudovicC.: Yes, and if that's a problem, a fix is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach using the interface offered by `memoir` to design a new chapter style; I also make some additional adjustments: the titles were always be placed inside a centered box which has a maximum width of 0.7\textwidth.

This approach allows to define the behaviour for both numbered and unnumbered chapters, without redefining internal commands:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{mystyle}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\scshape}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\scshape}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
    \chapnamefont\centering\@chapapp}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\itshape}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
\makebox[\linewidth][c]{\makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth+4em\relax][c]{%
    \hrulefill\hspace{1em}\raisebox{-.65ex}{\begin{varwidth}{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-2em\relax}\centering\chaptitlefont##1\end{varwidth}}\hspace*{1em}\hrulefill}}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vskip\afterchapskip}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{%
    \vphantom{\chapnumfont \textit{9}}\afterchapternum}
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Implementation}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter{A long title spanning more than one line}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter*{A title for an unnumbered chapter}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

An image for a numbered chapter with a short title:

[image]

An image for a numbered chapter with a longer title:

[image]

An image for an unnumbered chapter:

[image]